# Browserstack - Not able to use browser.get on mobile devices

Tags: selenium, protractor, mocha.js, browserstack

So I am trying to do something very simple yet so hard to understand for me the reason why its not working.

I am using browserstack combined with protractor and it is as simple as adding this to the config:

```
let SpecReporter = require('mochawesome').SpecReporter;

exports.config = {

    baseUrl: 'http://testing.net/',

    "browserstackUser": "test",
    "browserstackKey": "1234",

    multiCapabilities: [
        {
            os_version: "9.0",
            device: "Samsung Galaxy S10 Plus",
            real_mobile: false,
            browserName: "Android",
            project: "Selenium-Test",
            build: "Build 1337",
            name: "Mobile - Happy Flow"
        }
    ],

    mochaOpts: {
        reporter: "mochawesome",
        timeout: 60000, 
    },

    suites: {
        all: 'pages/*.js',
    },

    framework: 'mocha',

};
```

and whenever I run the code it starts by:

```
describe('FIRST TEST', function () {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    brwoser.get('http://testing.net/');
}
```

and it seems to be stuck through here. I was watching the live demo of what is happening and it seems like it doesn't want to open the URL even thought I do have the link which is odd. and I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong for mobile version but yeah.

The problem is I can't open any URL for the phones but works well on desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you remove browser.manage().window().maximize(); for the mobile code

Answer (score 0):

You can review a sample provided by BrowserStack in the link: https://github.com/browserstack/protractor-browserstack and execute the tests on similar lines